# abstract base class problem when iterating through vector of pointers to objects

Tags: c++

Hello i am having a specific conceptual problem with abstract base classes i will demonstrate my question in an example with chess classes. I define an abstract base class piece and three other classes pawn bishop and pawn i write these in the following way.

```
class piece{
    public:
    wchar_t type;
    wchar_t get_piece_symbol() const {return type;}
    virtual bool legit_move(int displacement)=0;
    virtual ~piece(){}
};

class pawn: public piece{
    
    public:
    wchar_t type;
    bool move_is_legit(int displacement){....}
    wchar_t get_piece_symbol() const {return type;}
    .....
};

class knight:public piece{
    
    public:
    bool move_is_legit(int displacement){....}
    wchar_t get_piece_symbol() const {return type;}
    ....
};

class bishop:public piece{
   
    public:
    bool move_is_legit(int displacement){....}
    wchar_t get_piece_symbol() const {return type;}
    ....
};
```

The legit_move function makes the piece class abstract.However let's say i want to do the following in the main

```
std::vector<piece*> Board(64);

piece* a{}; 


for(int i{0}; i<64; i++){
    Board[i] = a;
   
}

knight *knight_1 = knight{....};
bishop *bishop_1 = bishop{....};
....

Board.at(4)= knight_1
Board.at(4)= bishop_1
....
```

Essentially what i try to do is create a vector called board containing pointers to pieces. First i fill the Board with pointers to the abstract base class piece(dont know if this makes sense actually) and then i start filling positions of the board with pointers to knight bishop objects etc. So i want to do the following

```
   for(Board_iterator=Board_begin;
            Board_iterator<Board_end;++Board_iterator){

               

                std::cout<< (*Board_iterator) -> get_piece_type();
            }


}
```

Essentially for each piece on the board i want to get its symbol when iterating through the vector, but if the Board iterator points to a piece object (abstract base class) the terminal just stops there, is there a way to go about this, so in cases where the Board_iterator corresponds to a piece class pointer can i make some kind of condition to know when this is happening?

Comment: There is no inheritance in the code you've shown. Consider putting together a [mcve] to show what you're trying to do and where you're having a problem.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to put the ":public piece" to make the rest of the classes derived classes, i was trying to make the example look simple and forgot about the important stuff i have updated the skeleton code

Comment: "First i fill the Board with pointers to the abstract base class piece(dont know if this makes sense actually)" It doesn't seem to. You cannot create an object of an abstract class. What do you want your pointers to point at?

Comment: Why not just let the empty squares be pointers to NULL?  If you need it to point to something then it shouldn't point to pieces - it should point to squares that contain a piece.